# AngularJS <a> tag links not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an index of objects returned from search. The template has an ng-repeat where the item's URL is constructed from data in the model but in the final markup the "a" tag does not work. The ng-href and href are correct, the URL bar changes when the link is clicked but the page does not load. Doing a browser refresh after the click does get the page. So something in Angular is changing the URL bar but not triggering a load???

Can't make this reproduce in a jsfiddle because the problem seems to be in loading the json into the template after a $resource.query() function, which I can't do from a jsfiddle. With a simulated query loading static data the jsfiddle works even though the final markup looks identical.

The AngularJS template looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="VideoSearchResultsCtrl" class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12" >
    <div class="video_thumb" ng-repeat="video in videos">
      <p>
        <a ng-href="/guides/{{video._id}}" data-method="get">
          <img ng-src="{{video.poster.large_thumb.url}}">
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The results look fine and produce the following final markup:

```
<div ng-controller="VideoSearchResultsCtrl" class="row-fluid ng-scope">
  <div class="span12">
    <!-- ngRepeat: video in videos --><div class="video_thumb ng-scope" ng-repeat="video in videos">
      <p>
        <a ng-href="/guides/5226408ea0eef2d029673a80" data-method="get" href="/guides/5226408ea0eef2d029673a80">
          <img ng-src="/uploads/video/poster/5226408ea0eef2d029673a80/large_thumb_2101146_det.jpg" src="/uploads/video/poster/5226408ea0eef2d029673a80/large_thumb_2101146_det.jpg">
        </a>
      </p>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: video in videos -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The controller code is:

```
GuideControllers.controller('VideoSearchResultsCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'VideoSearch',
    function($scope, $location, VideoSearch) {
        $scope.videos = VideoSearch.query({ namespace: "api", resource: "videos", action: 'search', q: $location.search().q });
    }
]);
```

Using AngularJS 1.2-rc.3. I've also tried using an ng-click and regular old onclick to get a page loaded even with static URL but the clicks never trigger the code. BTW static non-angular links on this page do work, so the Menu Bar and Sign Out work.

What have I done wrong here or is this a bug in AngularJS?

Comment: Are you using `ngRoute`? Is there a `<base>` tag in your page?

Comment: can use plunker to load json very easily for demos

Comment: load json but not from a server running on my laptop. It turned out the be a $locationProvider configured to HTML5, see below. So nothing to do with loading, just didn't put the locationProvider config in the jsfiddle.

In general I alway try to reproduce on plnkr or jsfiddle but many problems are too complex. This one is a good example.

@Blackhole, no to both. It was HTML5 mode that got me.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

From the mailing list I got an answer:

> Have you by any chance configured your $locationProvider to
>   html5Mode? If yes this would cause your problems. You could force it
>   to always go to the url by adding target="_self" to your  tag. Give
>   it a shot.

I had configured to use HTML5 so adding the `target="_self"` to the tag fixed the problem. Still researching why this works.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly my problem. Unfortunately, the Angular doc page isn't very helpful, saying only that this flag enables "Use HTML5 strategy if available."

Comment: @pferrel thank you! You have no idea how much time I've spent trying to fix my redirecting issue until I came across this post.

Comment: Just tried this and for me it reloads the whole page. Kind of self defeating in a SPA app. I don't want my shell to re-render and I'm pretty sure my frameworks and scripts/css are all reloaded (albeit they should be cached). I've got this working in a previous app so will continue looking for a way (can't tell from looking at previous code)

Comment: I just made mine work. My issue was I had not set up my route correctly. I was passing a parameter but had not defined the parameter in the route. So mine was a quick easy fix. However, my point above remains that when navigating with an SPA app we should never need to reload the entire app.

Comment: @Shumii did you ever figure out how to apply this solution without having your page reload? I'm experiencing the same complication.

Comment: This just saved me from a very embarrassing failed demo. I would kiss you if it wasn't weird and geographically impossible

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if this has been updated since this post was answered, but you can configure this in application startup. Setting the rewriteLinks to false re-enables your `a` tags, but still leaves `html5mode` on, which comes with all its own benefits. I have added a bit of logic around these settings to revert `html5mode` in browsers where `window.history` is not supported (IE8)

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {

    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: true,
            rewriteLinks: false
        });
    }
    else {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    }
}]);
```

[Angular Docs on $locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)

[The benefits of html5mode vs hashbang mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes)

Comment: @pferrel has temporary fix but your point is the permanent fix. "Setting the rewriteLinks to false re-enables your a tags". Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I know this post is old, but I recently ran into this problem as well. My .html page had the base

```
//WRONG!
<base href="/page" />
```

and the fix:

```
//WORKS!
<base href="/page/" />
```

notice the forward-slash ('/') after 'page'.

Not sure if this applies to other cases, but give it a try!

Comment: Hate to be pedantic, but `'/'` is a forward-slash. `'\'` is a backslash.  :)

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS suffers from a sparse documentation, I hope their gaining momentum will improve it. I think AngularJS is primarily intended as a [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), and maybe the idea behind deactivating by default all a tags allows one to easily incorporate angular into some already existing html.

This allows for quick refactoring of the default "routing" behaviour of a "traditional" website (well, script pages linked between each other) into the angular routing system, which is more of an MVC approach, better suited for Web Apps.

Answer (score 1):

Find this line:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

change it for:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')
```

and include this line in the head of index.html if you don't have it.

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Find this line... in which file? angular.js itself, or... ?  (I'm hoping we're not actually supposed to mess with the actual angular script.)

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old, but this is one of the top results on Google.
So if you are using Angular 7, and only want to link a couple of files, then just put the into the "assets" directory:

[image: Angular project structure for files]

Now when you want to link the file you can just use the href tag as below:

```html
  <img src="assets/ang_1.png" alt="Angular">
```

Note: you can only link to the assets folder by default, so you strictly have to place your files there.