# AngularJS prototype app page not loading after one link selection

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and am seeing odd behavior for a single page app that I am prototyping. After selecting a link into the navigation, subsequent clicks only load the page if the _blank attribute is set. What is preventing the page from loading in the same tab after the initial link selection?

```
<div ng-repeat="result in searchResult">
  {{result.display_text}}<br/>
  <a href="{{result.y_outcome}}">{{result.y_display}}</a><br/>
  <a href="{{result.n_outcome}}">{{result.n_display}}</a><br/>
</div>
```

I have a plunk of the prototype with the full code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/O1SP0kkOLVCul55fxg4F).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this via suggestions from: [AngularJS <a> tag links not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773682/angularjs-a-tag-links-not-working)

Essentially, I enabled html5Mode:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);    
}]);
```

Then, changed the href to use the ng-href directive and then added the target="_self" attribute.