# Cannot get current route. $location.path() returns empty.

Tags: angularjs

I am currently at `/addDoc`, and I want current route I am at. Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('DocRegistrationController',[ '$http', '$scope', '$upload', '$location', function($http, $scope, $upload, $location){
$scope.validation=function(){
   alert($location.path());
}
    }
```

However it returns empty. I dont want to hardcode all the routes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using `$routeProvider` in html5 mode (no `#` sign in url) or not?

Comment: i have not used $routeProvider, I want this for calling api from ajax call.

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.dir($location)`?

Comment: `  
$$protocol
 
 "http"
$$host
 
 "localhost"
$$port
 
 9090
$$parse
 
 function(d)
$$compose
 
 function()
$$rewrite
 
 function(a)
$$path
 
 ""
$$search
 
 Object {}
$$hash
 
 ""
$$url
 
 ""
$$absUrl
 
 "http://localhost:9090/addDoc"
$$replace
 
 false
$$html5
 
 false
absUrl
 
 function()
url
 
 function(a)
protocol
 
 function()
host
 
 function()
port
 
 function()
path
 
 function(c)
search
 
 function(a, c)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

$location service respond for parsing url in browser address bar and make the URL available to your APP.

Because you're using regular URL path and search segments, you have to set $locationProvider html5Mode to true.

$locationProvider will use hashbang as default mode.

If you don't set html5Mode to true, you will get empty string when you try to fetch url path.

Then use $location service to fetch the url path after set html5Mode.

And write your own rule to process the path.

Assume that your Full URL looks like: http://example.com/person/show/321

Main.js

```
angular.module("MyAPP",[],function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

function MainController($location){
    var pId = $location.path().split("/")[3]||"Unknown";    //path will be /person/show/321/, and array looks like: ["","person","show","321",""]
    console.log(pId);
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyAPP">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Angular test</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: setting the `html5Mode` to true gave rise to problem where I could not load any link to desired route, only the addressbar's address changed. I solved this problem with reference to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773682/angularjs-a-tag-links-not-working) question, putting `target='_self'` in the anchor tag.

Comment: If you configure `$location` to use `html5Mode (history.pushState)`, you need to specify the base URL for the application with a `<base href=""> `tag or configure `$locationProvider` to not require a base tag by passing a definition object with `requireBase:false` to `$locationProvider.html5Mode()`. Or you will get an error `Error: $location:nobase` as in https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

Comment: you need set base   requireBase: false in html5mode also otherwise you will get error .

Answer (score 1):

Use `$location.absUrl()`....Full URL Looks like : http://localhost:6292/Example/URLName

Answer (score 1):

Try also this, which is native code in JS. It worked for me. But if you need to parse long url with many nested pages, you have to modify the code a bit.

```
var path = "/" + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
  console.log(path
);
```