# links <a> does not navigate to desired route

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal given below, which is inside an angular contoller `registrationCtrl`, which pops up if re-registration is attempted. There is a `LOGIN` link at the footer of modal, however when I click the link, only the url in browser's addressbar changes. But the page does not navigate to `/login`, as it is supposed to.

```
<div class="modals">
    <div id="registered" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registeredModal" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal_container">
          <div id="modal-head"><span>Already Registered</span></div>
          <div class="modal_body">
              ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal_footer">
            <div id="notice"><span>*Please login to continue or cancel to register with different </span></div>
            <div class="buttons button-toolbar">
              <div class="login btn-vert-block">
                  <span><a href="/login">LOGIN</a></span>
              <div class="cancel btn-vert-block">  <!--the link that is not working-->
                  <span>
                     <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

The modal works perfectly when used as an independent html. What am I missing here?

Comment: It's most likely a path issue in that the Login page is relative to the route and your current page isn't. Best help is to use the Chrome dev tools to see what path it's actually looking for.

Comment: the url that shows in the address bar is the url I want it to navigate to... its just the url in address bar changes... but does not navigate...

Answer (score 0):

The link problem was in whole html page and not exclusive to the modal. I found out the problem arose from setting the `html5Mode` to `true`:

```
angular.module("MyAPP",[],function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

The link navigates if we put `target='_self'` in the anchor tag. I found the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773682/angularjs-a-tag-links-not-working). But I couldnt find the actual reason and explanation. If someone can give me the explanation that would be great help, as I am an angular beginner.