# URL link not redirecting properly in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-href

I have a link in my **announce.obj**. But when I clicked it, it's giving me the wrong url (http://www./) in the browser.

**html**

```
<p>
  <a ng-href="{{data.links}}" target="_blank">{{data.links}}</a>
</p>
```

**data.links value**

```
www.google.com
```

Should I add an **https** when saving my links in the db or something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this like `$scope.myVar = 'https://www.w3schools.com';`:

```js
var app = angular.module('myAngularApp', []);

var myController = app.controller('myController', MyController);

myController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MyController($scope){

    $scope.myVar = 'https://www.w3schools.com';

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body ng-app="myAngularApp">

<div ng-controller = "myController">
<h1>Tutorials</h1>
<p>Go to <a ng-href="{{myVar}}">{{myVar}}</a> to learn!</p>
</div>

<p>This example could use the original href attribute, but in AngularJS, the ng-href attribute is safer.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should have the value as,

```
http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

use `target="_self"` instead of `target="_blank"`

```js
angular.module("test",[]).controller("testCont",function($scope)
{
$scope.data={};
$scope.data.links="http://www.google.com/";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCont">
  <a ng-href="{{data.links}}" target="_self">{{data.links}}</a>

</div>
```

Comment: then try with full url and check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773682/angularjs-a-tag-links-not-working @Priz

Answer (score 0):

Give the data.links a complete url value, copy it from the mobile browser including the https//: and all , this is a case of the url not beibg recognized.